# compare two lines in the same file using sed or awk

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I want to compare a line that begin with a matching pattern and its next line

for example for the pattern DD

```
*DD 05 :(X):-Example
    05 :X:-Example
```

I want to have as result only the difference between this lines :

```
  (X) 
   X
```

Comment: why are the colons included?

Comment: yes ! thanks I will edit my question

Comment: how do you define the difference, why is it not just the parenthesis?

Comment: not clear: what is a difference for you (ex :`05 :(X):-Example\n05 :Y:-not(X) Example`) what to keep or exclude ?

Comment: @NeronLeVelu  in this case  `5 :(X):-Example\n05 :Y:-not(X)` I want to have this  result  (X) and Y

Answer (score 0):

*Greps* line with pattern and line after, *cuts* second field with colon as a separator and *reads* it to variables `$a` and `$b`.

```
$ read a b <<<$(grep -A1 '*DD' myfile | cut -d':' -f2)
$ echo $a
(X)
$ echo $b
X
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 'H;x
     /^\*DD/ !d
     s// /
     s/^\[[:blank:]]*\(.*\)\(.*\)\(.*\n\)[[:blank:]]*\1/\2\3/
     s/\(.*\)\(\n.*\)\1$/\2/' YourFile
```

- report for all your file based on your pattern (to avoid to set in 2 place, a add a line that remove it)
- posix
- try in 1 `s///` but pattern expansion in 1 direction make it failed so

  - second s/// remove header
  - third remove trailer

Answer (score 0):

awk -F: '{ print $2 }' file  
(X)    
X